# Removing double slashes from URL not quite working

Tags: .htaccess, mod-alias

I have a double slash in several of my URLs. I've fixed the problem that was causing the double slashes. But now I want to add 301 redirects so Google/Bing etc. know which is the correct page version. I attempted this with the htaccess rule, but my rule doesn't seem to be working. Anything wrong with this htaccess rule? Here it is,

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^//(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1
```

and this is an example of the URL I'm trying to match,

```
https://www.example.com//faq/
```

I want this to redirect to,

```
https://www.example.com/faq/
```

One thing I noticed was that when I type this URL,

```
https://www.example.com//faq
```

It seems to work. Have I written the rule wrong? I'm not the best with these!

Comment: If anyone has some good resources for learning htaccess rules more please share!

Answer (score 0):

Please check this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\/(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```